# Push Notification android using FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When sending notification through Firebase API calls `onMessageReceived()` even when the app is not running or killed but when sending through Firebase Console does not invoke `onMessageReceived()` when app is killed ?

Comment: where is your code

Comment: Check whether you have selected the app package name while sending notification form firebase console.

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 0):

FCM provide two types of messages .

1. **Notification messages** -sometimes thought of as "display messages." These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.

2.**Data messages**-which are handled by the client app.

> Notification messages are delivered to the notification tray when the app is in the background. For apps in the foreground, messages are handled by onMessageReceived():

For more information read [FCM messeges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some key-value pairs as a data payload from the **Firebase Console**. while composing message for notification you  have to select **Advanced options** and then add some data as a key value.
Once the app will get data notification, then the notification will be displayed in both the modes(background/killed and foregroud).

**Inside Firebase console(Compose message) :**

Advances options --> Add custom data(with key and value) --> Send